# How to group array by value with alphabet range

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, grouping

How to group array with the same value based on the alphabet range, 
I have an array like this.

```
$arr = array('HIGH','HIGH','HIGH','HIGH','LOW','LOW','LOW'
             ,'MEDIUM','MEDIUM');
$alpabet = range('a','z');

foreach ($arr as $key => $val){
    echo $alpabet[$key].' - '.$val."</br>";
}
```

result from this code

```
a - HIGH
b - HIGH
c - HIGH
d - HIGH
e - LOW
f - LOW
g - LOW
h - MEDIUM
i - MEDIUM
```

how to get result like this

```
a - HIGH
a - HIGH
a - HIGH
a - HIGH
b - LOW
b - LOW
b - LOW
c - MEDIUM
c - MEDIUM
```

Comment: o.O how are you associating these letters to values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this magic loop:

```
$tmp = [];
$i = -1;
foreach ($arr as $val){
    $tmp[$val] = empty($tmp[$val]) ? $alpabet[++$i] : $tmp[$val];
    echo $tmp[$val].' - '.$val.PHP_EOL;  
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2PbET)**

Outputs:

```
a - HIGH
a - HIGH
a - HIGH
a - HIGH
b - LOW
b - LOW
b - LOW
c - MEDIUM
c - MEDIUM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this code:

```
$prev_value = ''; // you need it to check for new values
$alphabet_range_index = -1; // every new value you increment this index

foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    if ($val != $prev_value) {
        // every new value you increment the alphabet index
        $alphabet_range_index++;
        $prev_value = $val;
    }
    echo $alpabet[$alphabet_range_index].' - '.$val."</br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create a map of values from `$arr` to keys in `$alphabet`.

```
$map = array_flip(array_values(array_unique($arr)));
```

(This will give you `$map = ['HIGH' => 0, 'LOW' => 1, 'MEDIUM' => 2]`)

Then you can use that in your loop to match values from `$arr` with values from `$alphabet`.

```
echo $alpabet[$map[$val]].' - '.$val."</br>";
```

---

A similar method would be to map the values from `$arr` directly to letters.

```
$unique = array_unique($arr);
$map = array_combine($unique, array_slice($alphabet, 0, count($unique)));
```

This will give you `$map = ['HIGH' => 'a', 'LOW' => 'b', 'MEDIUM' => 'c']`, which you can use in the loop like

```
echo $map[$val].' - '.$val."</br>";
```

---

This idea makes a few assumptions about the starting array and the goal, and the question is not too specific in that respect, so it may not meet your needs. Still, it could be valid for some situations like this.